# Integrate $\int \frac{1}{1+ \tan x}dx$

Tags: calculus

Does this integral have a closed form?

$$\int \frac{1}{1+ \tan x}\,dx$$

My attempt:

$$\int \frac{1}{1+ \tan x}\,dx=\ln (\sin x + \cos x) +\int \frac{\tan x}{1+ \tan x}\,dx$$

What is next?

Answer (score 7):

$$
I=\int  \frac 1 {1+\tan  x} \, dx=\int \frac {\cos x}{\cos x +\sin x} \, dx\\
J=\int \frac {\sin x}{\cos x +\sin x} \, dx\\
I+J=\int \frac {\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x +\sin x} \, dx = x+C_1\\ \\
I-J=\int \frac {\cos x-\sin x}{\cos x +\sin x} \,dx=\int \frac { d\left( \sin x +\cos x\right)  }{ \cos x +\sin x} =\ln \left| \sin x +\cos x \right| + C_2 \\
2I = x+\ln \left| \sin x +\cos x\right| + C_3 \\
I=\frac 1 2 \left[ x+\ln \left| \sin x +\cos x \right| + C_3 \right]
$$

Comment: Writing \int { \frac{ {\cos} {x + {\sin { x } }  } }{ \cos { x + {\sin} { x}}} dx } where \int \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, dx would suffice doesn't serve a purpose and makes editing harder.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thank you for editing, but I am still can't find better-writing program rather than this one http://s1.daumcdn.net/editor/fp/service_nc/pencil/Pencil_chromestore.html

Comment: Notice this code: \int \frac{\cos x + \sin x}{\cos x + \sin x} \, dx. That's not really complicated. Do you need a program to do that?

Comment: yes, it is not, but many such formulas take a track of time to do so

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$\int \frac{\tan{x}}{1+\tan{x}}= \int 1-\frac{1}{1+\tan{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Continuation from the Work in the Question**
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{1+\tan(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\log(\sin(x)+\cos(x))+\int\frac{\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac12\log(\sin(x)+\cos(x))+\frac12\int\frac{1+\tan(x)}{1+\tan(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac12(x+\log(\sin(x)+\cos(x)))+C\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: copied from the question
$(2)$: average the left and right sides of $(1)$
$(3)$: $\int1\,\mathrm{d}x=x+C$

---

**Another Approach**

One can also try $u=\tan(x)$ and partial fractions:
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+\tan(x)}
&=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\tan(x)}{(1+\tan(x))\left(1+\tan^2(x)\right)}\tag4\\
&=\int\frac12\left(\frac1{1+u}+\frac{1-u}{1+u^2}\right)\mathrm{d}u\tag5\\
&=\frac12\left(\log(1+u)+\tan^{-1}(u)-\frac12\log\left(1+u^2\right)\right)+C\tag6\\
&=\frac12(x+\log(\sin(x)+\cos(x)))+C\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: $\mathrm{d}\tan(x)=\left(1+\tan^2(x)\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$
$(5)$: $u=\tan(x)$ and partial fractions
$(6)$: integrate
$(7)$: backsubstitute

Answer (score 0):

$$ \tan x=\frac {2\tan x/2}{1+\tan^2 x/2}$$
Solves your integral with $$u=\tan x/2$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$(\log(\sin x\pm\cos x))'=\frac{\cos x\mp\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x}$$

Then

$$(\log(\sin x+\cos x)+\log(\sin x-\cos x))'=(\log(\sin^2x-\cos^2x))'=\frac{2\cos x}{\sin x+\cos x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

How about:
$$\int\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}dx= \ln(\sin(x)+\cos(x)) +\int\frac{\tan(x)}{1+tan(x)}dx= \ln(\sin(x)+\cos(x)) +\int\left(1-\frac{1}{1+\tan(x)}\right)dx$$
$$\therefore I= \ln(\sin(x)+\cos(x))+x-I$$
$$\therefore I=\frac{\ln(\sin(x)+\cos(x))+x}{2}+C $$

Answer (score 0):

If the numerator and denominator are both polynomials of trigonometric functions, then the substitution $y= \tan(x/2)$ should always work. It is not necessarily the shortest solution, but it works.